# Getting ENOENT Error in Angular for the node_modules

Tags: angular-cli

I have already installed all the setup and the localhost:4200 was up until i restarted my cmd. Then it started throwing the following error:

An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\Angular\node_modules'
See "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-2I8V3S\angular-errors.log" for further details.

Pls help!

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a solution to this problem.

I had this problem

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
],
```

Should have been

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
],
```

This caused it to look for node_modules in the wrong place